# Why my Date field is showing corrupted layout when i click on the calendar icon

Tags: 2013, development, administration, list-form

I have a team site inside my sharepoint 2013 on-premises site. and i have a Date field inside my custom list, but when i click on the calendar icon i got this corrupted layout, as follow:-

[image]

so can anyone advice on this ? now i noted that all the date fields inside a certain site collection will have this issue.. while on other site collections the calendar will be showed correctly as follow:-

[image]

and i did my test using IE & firefox, both have the same issue.

Comment: The image that you're seeing is /images/spcommong.png, which should be styled using classes from defaultcsss.ashx. Is your browser loading this stylesheet?

Comment: Is this using a custom masterpage? See: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62908/broken-datepicker-calendar-popup/66172

Comment: @OmarStewey yes this is a custom master page,, but i am using the same master page on other site collections and the calendar is working well..

Comment: @m4d yes the browser is loading the stylesheet since the calendar is working on other site collections without any issues...